# I can't figure it out why this happen in my C++ code

Tags: c++

I first read and stored some int numbers in a vector called `my`, then I'm trying to sum first `size` number. This is the code I've done:

```cpp
vector<int>my;
cout << "please enter num:" << endl;
int item;
while(cin>>item){
    my.push_back(item);
}
cout << endl;
for(auto i:my){
    cout << i << " ";
}
    
cout << "\nplease enter the num you want to sum: " << endl;
int size;
cin >> size;
    
vector<int>myvector;
for(int i=0;i<size;++i){
    myvector.push_back(my[i]);
}
    
cout << "\nthe nums are: ";
int total{0};
for(auto t:myvector){
    cout << t << " ";
    total += t;
}
cout << "\nthe total is: " << total << endl;
```

Result:

```
please enter num:
3
1
2
3
4
5
]

3 1 2 3 4 5 
please enter the num you want to sum: 

the nums are: 
the total is: 0
```

Like you see, from the second prompt, the code wasn't working, didn't give me the results I expected, so I simply moved the second prompt to the top, then it's working;

```cpp
cout << "\nplease enter the num you want to sum: " << endl;
int size;
cin >> size;
    
vector<int>my;
cout << "please enter num:" << endl;
int item;
while(cin>>item){
    my.push_back(item);
}
cout << endl;
for(auto i:my){
    cout << i << " ";
}
    
    
vector<int>myvector;
for(int i=0;i<size;++i){
    myvector.push_back(my[i]);
}
    
cout << "\nthe nums are: ";
int total{0};
for(auto t:myvector){
    cout << t << " ";
    total += t;
}
cout << "\nthe total is: " << total << endl;
```

```
please enter the num you want to sum: 
3
please enter num:
1
2
3
4
5
]

1 2 3 4 5 
the nums are: 1 2 3 
the total is: 6
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `while(cin>>item){` will continue reading from `cin` until the stream is closed. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: @scohe001 It seems that OP is trying to "stop" cin by entering `]`, which unfortunately is also why their program doesn't work

Comment: OT, but what is `myvector` for? Why does it have to be a different object from `my`? And why can't you initialize it as `vector<int>myvector = my;`? Also, what happens if `size` is different from the actual number of elements in `my`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. I thought if I use the "while" loop to read and store some int # in the vector is a good approach. and when I enter a non-int # which in my case I use "]" to end the while loop which also ended the stream. so this should work. correct me if Im wrong.

Comment: Giving a non-integer input will set the fail state of the stream. As long as a stream is in the fail state, you can't use it to read any input. You must `clear` the state.

Comment: thank you for your answer. if that's the case, after I moved the second prompt to the top and I used non-inter input to end the while loop, this also set the fail state of the stream, but why the rest code worked fine?

Comment: The reason it works when you read `size` first is that you're not using a `while` loop there to repeat the `>> size` until an error occurs, so it's not already in an error state when you reach `while (cin>>item)`.  Regarding Some programmer dude's advice, if you wanted to continue to use a stream after an error, you have to both `clear` the error state *and* `ignore` the unwanted input: people normally discard everything up to and including the next newline.  Search for "std::cin clear error" and it should turn up the necessary code / examples / explanations.

Comment: got it. thank you guys very much, cool.

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out in comments, your `while (std::cin >> item)` reads until the stream `std::cin` turns into a failure state, e.g., when entering a non-digit (more precisely, `std::ios_base::failbit` gets set on the stream's state, i.e., `std::cin.fail()` will return `true`). It will remain in that state until the stream state gets cleared. That is, you can use

```
while (std::cin >> item) {
    my.push_back(item);
}

std::cin.clear();  // clear the failure state of the stream
std::cin.ignore(); // ignore the next character

int size;
if (!(std::cin >> size)) {
    std::cout << "failed to read an integer from standard input\n";
    // do some error recovery, e.g., bail out of the program
}
// carry on with your processing
```

Personally, I would be inclined to read the data from `std::cin` directly into the vector, e.g., using

```
std::vector<int> my{std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
                    std::istream_iterator<int>()};
```

Of course, the stream still needs to be `clear()`ed and the separating character `ignore()`ed.